# Saving files automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I have data being imported into a single text file every 10 min. Once a day my excel file called book1 opens automatically at 5pm and runs a macro. This macro imports data (from the text file), graphs it, saves the file, then closes both the saved file and book1.

I need files to save into the same location but a different file name for each day. It could be LOGTEST1, LOGEST2. or DAY1, or DAY2. The file name doesn't matter, so long as once a day a new file appears on my savedlocation. In 30 days, I should have 30 files.

This is the code I have to save it as a single file. Can anyone help me to save it dynamically using the same macro and the same book1 file?

```
Sub Auto_Open()
'
' Auto_Open Macro
'

'
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\Pabo\Desktop\LOGTEST.txt", Origin _
        :=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote _
        , ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Comma:= _
        False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 4), Array(2, 1) _
        ), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("A:B").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'LOGTEST'!$A:$B")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\LOGTEST.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges = True
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your file name to include today's day and month for instance. Something like:

```
myFileName = "myFile_" & Month(Now) & "_" & Day(Now)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\" & myFileName, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```